# ページ内アンカーを設置したい時は、<a name="xxx">を使うべきなのでしょうか？

Tags: html

`<a>` タグの主な用途として、ハイパーリンクの他に、`<a name="hoge">` によるページ内アンカーの設置があるかと思います。しかし実際のところは他のタグでも機能するようですし、name属性のほかにid属性を使っても正しくジャンプできます。

それでもやはり `<a name="xxx">` を使った方がよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 既にある回答でも指摘されていますが、HTML5では廃止されてますが、（HTML4.1を対象としているような）古いブラウザでの閲覧ためにということですか？ そういう場合の折衷案としては`<a name="xxx" id="xxx">`もありだと思います。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY いえ、特にそういうことは考えておらず、現在のHTMLではどうなのだろうと思った次第です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a`要素の`name`属性は**HTML5で廃止**されています。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Obsolete

もちろん互換性のため機能していますが、アンカーにはname属性ではなくidを使うべきです。